# Obtener subkey de JSON

Tags: jquery, json

estoy intentando crear una tabla dinámica en base a un JSON. El problema esta en que necesito hacer que la cabecera de la tabla se rellene con los datos de una subkeys, es decir, yo tengo lo siguiente:

```
{
"num_prod": 17,
"total": 17,
"articulo": [
    {
        "nombre": "Camiseta",
        "talla": "XL",
        "dsc": "100%"
    }
```

Pues necesito que la cabecera se rellene con nombre, talla y dsc de forma dinámica, ya que el objetivo es que se pueda usar para mas bases de datos sin tener que estar modificando el codigo. Me han sugerido Object.keys, pero me dan los valores num_prod, total y articulo. Muchas gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saca los nombres de los campos (para las celdas `<th>`) con `Object.keys(data.articulo[0])`.

Luego itera con un `for (var i = 0; i < data.articulo.length; i++)`.

Comment: Me ha servido perfecto, muchas gracias.

Comment: @AntonioMP87  ¡De nada!